I recently bought a Lexar SL500 SSD and sometimes some files are randomly corrupted
Like some lines of code become some garbage I think that important to note is that I travel with this drive and switch it between laptop and main PC.
Every time it happens I run chkdsk and it shows me that corruption was found on drive on those locations.

Check if the SSD is genuine - there are a bunch of fake/scams SSD's where a small SSD is re-badged with a larger capacity and custom firmware installed to make it report as larger. They typically work fine with only a few files on them, but as soon as the "true" capacity fills up they exhibit the symptoms you describe.

Ill try to find receipt and refund it. But im suprised because i bought it from certified store, so I assume they dont sell fake products

Additionally it has very good verified reviews so maybe its something wrong with mine
